# How to implement wait in a method call in generic way

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a generic solution for third party API(work in async way) but not getting any idea that how i can implement a call for rest of my application in synchronized way. Basically API is working like take request, process it and then give response when it finish but in meanwhile open to receive other requests as well. So i put API response method in a thread so that monitor continuously either there is a response or not by calling api response method with time interval.

API have interface to take request like:

```
public void api_execute(string UUID,String request);
```

API response object:

```
public APIReponse
{
private String UUID;
private String response_string
 // Getter setter
}
```

I want to write a wrapper on top of this API in which have a single method so that different objects of my application use this to send request and receive response. so UUID will be create by this wrapper class but i am not getting that how i will wait a caller object until i received some response and also distinguish which caller send which request. I was thinking by using observer pattern here but seems to be not fit with this scenario. Can someone give me a hint how i can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You create async task executor using thread pool

```
ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        public Future<APIReponse> submitTask(APIRequest request) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            System.out.println("Submitting Task ...");
            Future<APIReponse> future = threadpool.submit(new Callable<APIReponse>() {

                @Override
                public APIReponse call() throws Exception {
                    api_execute(request,UUID);

                    return new APIReponse();
                }

            });
            return future;
```

Comment: I never used ExecuterService before but it seems to be interesting. Should i need to use inside of method directly and where it should be distinguish a response based on request UUID?

Comment: It will return a future to a calling method .For a given request on future response will return